# Can I use a GridSplitter to drag a column without resizing it?

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

The following code is intended to represent a resizeable viewport (the "black border") and I can use the lateral GridSplitters to resize the viewport rectangle.

What I would like to do is, by dragging the middle GridSplitter, to move the whole border, that is, adjust the width of first and last columns, while keeping the width of other columns.

Is that possible? I don't mind some code-behind, but I'd like to believe that maybe it's not necessary?

```
<Window x:Class="GridSplitterViewport.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridSplitterViewport"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="259*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="ViewPort" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="#3000" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 4"/>

        <GridSplitter x:Name="ResizeLeft" Grid.Column="1" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <GridSplitter x:Name="Move" ResizeDirection="Columns" Grid.Column="2" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <GridSplitter x:Name="ResizeRight" Grid.Column="3" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="ViewPort" Grid.Column="1" Background="#3000" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 4"/>

    <GridSplitter x:Name="ResizeLeft" Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="6" Margin="-6,0,0,0"/>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="Move" ResizeDirection="Columns" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="ResizeRight" Grid.Column="2" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="6"/>

</Grid>
```